Just Audio: How to dynamically mix audio files
I have a number of audio files on the disk (6 to be precise) each containing one instrument of a song (vocals, bass, drums etc.). The files (let's call them tracks) have the same duration and are in the same format (.mp3).
I want to mix these audio files during playback (as in "layering" them; playing them simultaneously). This in itself is not too hard, I just convert the files to .wav and mix the pwm streams (it would be cool if there was a way to do this with mp3-files though, and not having to convert them first).
What I am unable to figure out is how to do this "dynamically", meaning being able to, during playback, change the volume or even mute of one of the tracks. Currently I reload the audio source each time with the changes in volume, but that causes a delay each time. Any ideas on how this could be implemented without having to reload the audio source?

I didn't understand honestly, do you need to play all the files at the same time, or do you need to collect all the files like a playlist?

I'm sorry, I have updated my question with additional information. Let me know if things are still unclear.

Hi, did you find a solution to this?

No, sadly not. I'm stuck with reloading the entire audio for the time being, which is far from optimal. If anyone has an idea how this could be implemented, please let me know.
